# Recover from missing class in Groovy script

Tags: groovy

I would like to refer to a class that might not be on classpath of a groovy script. But it fails with:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
script_from_command_line: 1: unable to resolve class my.class.Here
```

Is there any way I can recover from such problem *from within the script* or write the script in a different way so I can make the logic that depends on classes that might not be present optional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the solutions is to never refer to the types that might not be present and use `Class.forName(...)` to load the classes. Then `ClassNotFoundException` needs to be coughed and use as a signal the class(es) are not present.

This is quite limiting as not all class literal uses can be replaced by method calls.